# Input Variables not defined?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a program that sorts students scores along with their names into grade lists. I am struggling with why the score input variables (these are all the variables such as s1, s2, bs1, bs2, etc) are listed as "undefined" and thus cause an error.

```
def M4(scores, students, grades):
    global sfn, sln, ss, CA, st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6, st7, st8, st9, st10, CB, bst1, bst2, bst3, bst4, bst5, bst6, bst7, bst8, bst9, bst10, CC, cst1, cst2, cst3, cst4, cst5, cst6, cst7, cst8, cst9, cst10, CD, dst1, dst2, dst3, dst4, dst5, dst6, dst7, dst8, dst9, dst10, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, bf1, bf2, bf3, bf4, bf5, bf6, bf7, bf8, bf9, bf10, bl1, bl2, bl3, bl4, bl5, bl6, bl7, bl8, bl9, bl10, bs1, bs2, bs3, bs4, bs5, bs6, bs7, bs8, bs9, bs10, cf1, cf2, cf3, cf4, cf5, cf6, cf7, cf8, cf9, cf10, cl1, cl2, cl3, cl4, cl5, cl6, cl7, cl8, cl9, cl10, cs1, cs2, cs3, cs4, cs5, cs6, cs7, cs8, cs9, cs10, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, dl1, dl2, dl3, dl4, dl5, dl6, dl7, dl8, dl9, dl10, ds1, ds2, ds3, ds4, ds5, ds6, ds7, ds8, ds9, ds10
    for grade in grades:
        grade_list = grade[0]  # A, B
        min_value = grade[1]
        max_value = grade[2]

    if score in range(min_value, max_value):
        student = students[index]

        grade_list.append(student)
        grade_list.append(score)



    return grades


def main():
    global sfn, sln, ss, CA, st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6, st7, st8, st9, st10, CB, bst1, bst2, bst3, bst4, bst5, bst6, bst7, bst8, bst9, bst10, CC, cst1, cst2, cst3, cst4, cst5, cst6, cst7, cst8, cst9, cst10, CD, dst1, dst2, dst3, dst4, dst5, dst6, dst7, dst8, dst9, dst10, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, bf1, bf2, bf3, bf4, bf5, bf6, bf7, bf8, bf9, bf10, bl1, bl2, bl3, bl4, bl5, bl6, bl7, bl8, bl9, bl10, bs1, bs2, bs3, bs4, bs5, bs6, bs7, bs8, bs9, bs10, cf1, cf2, cf3, cf4, cf5, cf6, cf7, cf8, cf9, cf10, cl1, cl2, cl3, cl4, cl5, cl6, cl7, cl8, cl9, cl10, cs1, cs2, cs3, cs4, cs5, cs6, cs7, cs8, cs9, cs10, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, dl1, dl2, dl3, dl4, dl5, dl6, dl7, dl8, dl9, dl10, ds1, ds2, ds3, ds4, ds5, ds6, ds7, ds8, ds9, ds10
    A, B, C, D, P, E = [], [], [], [], [], []

    # So I'm constructing a "package" with all the important bits
    # we need from the grades:
    # 1. The list containing the students within the grade (empty for now)
    # 2. The minimum value to fit this grade (i.e., min <= x)
    # 3. The maximum value to fit this grade (excluding the actual value, i.e., x < max)
    Agrade = [A, 90, 100]
    Bgrade = [B, 80, 89]
    Cgrade = [C, 70, 79]
    Dgrade = [D, 60, 69]
    Pgrade = [P, 50, 59]
    Egrade = [E, 0, 49]

    grades = [Agrade, Bgrade, Cgrade, Dgrade, Pgrade, Egrade]

    # Don't need to convert the list to string here
    scores = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, bs1, bs2, bs3, bs4, bs5, bs6, bs7, bs8, bs9, bs10, cs1, cs2, cs3, cs4, cs5, cs6, cs7, cs8, cs9, cs10, ds1, ds2, ds3, ds4, ds5, ds6, ds7, ds8, ds9, ds10]
    students = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, bf1, bf2, bf3, bf4, bf5, bf6, bf7, bf8, bf9, bf10, cf1, cf2, cf3, cf4, cf5, cf6, cf7, cf8, cf9, cf10, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10]

    grades = M4(scores, students, grades)

    for grade in grades:
        print(grade[0])  # Print just the list
        print("\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know it's probably messy, but i'm new to python and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: He CrustyKing, where are these variables coming from?  I never seen such a structure before.  Variables need to be assigned values, something which is not happening here.

Comment: The variables are coming from a previous function in the program, the variables work fine in multiple different functions so i'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Well, based on the program above, it is hard to give an answer on your question, because somehow your variables don't get properly initialized and the problem isn't here. So you need to post more of the program. 

Besides that, I think you have deeper problems with your code. In python it is not normal to use globals this way. Usually globals aren't used at all. 

So perhaps you want to visit code review. They can help you make the structure of your code better.

Comment: That is not meant unfriendly btw, but I noticed you are learning python.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll look in restructuring my code. I agree that it's way to messy